# Replacing a default Express/Connect JS file with customized source code

Tags: node.js, express, node.js-connect

I modified JS source files in `my_server_root_folder/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/middleware/`. I would like to make a copy of the custom file and use my version instead of the one installed by npm in the path I mentioned above. If I make a copy of the 'connect' module and install it in `my_server_root_folder/node_modules/connect` how do I direct Express to use that module instead of the one installed in `my_server_root_folder/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect`?

Answer (score 2):

you could use symbolic link

`ln -s target_path link_path`

this way you can only maintain 1 version of the modified file, and link to it from other locations;

second approach is to clone Connect, make all necessary changes to it, and reference your cloned version in you projects.